About a classic explanation of $\mathcal A=\pi R^2$ for a disk
In a recent post, OP deals with a well known explanation of the formula $$\mathcal A=\pi R^2$$once you know $$p=2\pi R$$
When this explanation is given, it is usually sufficient to say that the areas obtained have as their "limit" the area of the rectangle of sides $$R \text{ and }\pi R$$

Questions :
1.- Can we prove that the classical form obtained by reassembling the portions of disks converges in the sense of the Hausdorff distance to the rectangle of sides $R$ and $\pi R$?
2.- Can we prove using argument of question 1 that the area of the disk is then $\pi R^2$?

My attempts: I know $h$, Hausdorff distance between two compacts.
Let us denote $\mathcal H:=\{K\subset \mathcal P(\mathbb R^2): K \text{ is a compact of } \mathbb R^2 \}$
I've never thought about whether the function $\mathcal A: \mathcal H\to \mathbb R^+$ is only defined but here we have very simple compacts as illustrated below , but above all continues
I've chosen $R=5$. So, the the arcs of the circle have a length of $$\frac{10\pi}{8}\approx 3.93$$
I haven't calculated $$h(BD'G'H',H'B'I''I')$$even though it should be quite simple but I'm not sure it's necessarily useful.

I hope that this question, where I would so much like to see the members of MSE gradually working, is not a dupe, and that it will be of interest to you.

See my first comment on @Vercassivelaunos' answer, please.

I don't have any pictures ready, but I hope my descriptions are sufficient. You may want to draw the figures I'm describing so it's easier to follow.
The idea will be the following: for any number $n$ of sectors, after rearranging there is a nearly rectangular figure for which there exists:

a minimal horizontal rectangle of area $A_n$ that fits around the rearranges disc
a maximal horizontal rectangle of area $a_n$ that fits inside the rearranged disc

These satisfy $a_n\leq A\leq A_n$, where $A$ is the area of the disc. And as $n\to\infty$, both $a_n$ and $A_n$ converge to the same number, which must then be equal to $A$ according to the Sandwich theorem. We just have to find their limits.
Preliminaries:
Note that each sector of the disc covers an angle of $\varphi_n=\frac{2\pi}{n}$. Each sector consists of an isosceles triangle and a disc segment. The segment has a chord of length $c_n=2R\sin(\varphi_n/2)$ and height $h_n=R(1-\cos(\varphi_n/2))$. The triangle has a height $H_n=R\cos(\varphi_n/2)$.
The outer rectangle:
The circumscribed rectangle has height $H_n+2h_n=R(1+\cos(\varphi_n/2))$. It also has width $\frac{n+1}{2}c_n=(n+1)R\sin(\varphi_n/2)$.
This yields $A_n=R^2(n+1)\sin(\varphi_n/2)[1+\cos(\varphi_n/2)]$. The limit as $n\to\infty$ is equal to that of $R^2n\sin(\varphi_n/2)$ according to limit arithmetic. Using l'Hospital (try justifying it yourself, it's not immediately apparent) this tends to $\pi R^2$.
The inner rectangle:
Similarly, the inscribed rectangle has height $H_n$ and width $\frac{n-1}{2}c_n$. Same as above we can calculate $a_n$ and show that it converges to $\pi R^2$.

Illustration: 

Thank you very much. I'm reading your post while making drawings. The connection with Hausdorff's distance remains to be made, but it shouldn't be very difficult with the ideas you bring to the table. This link is of great interest to me, as here for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4882574/largest-circle-contained-within-a-triangle

I made the drawings on geogebra. If you want, I can edit your post to include them.

@StéphaneJaouen you're welcome to do so!

If the illustration is not correct or does not suit you, I leave you free to delete it. However, here is a link because not everything is to be thrown away.https://www.geogebra.org/classic/gudzw2sn
